# TensorFlow naming: capitalized or not?

Tags: tensorflow

Why does TensorFlow mix capitalized and non-capitalized naming? I don't think it make sense. Maybe it's due to some legacy code?

Below are some examples

- `tf.constant()`, `tf.Variable()`
- `tf.Session().run()`

Comment: Thanks. So constant() is a function call, while Variable() calls class constructor.

Comment: correct, "constant" is an API call like "zeros" or "ones" which adds a constant node to the graph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It uses pep8, functions are snake case, classes are camel case.